# Is $x^4+2x^2-8m^2x+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Is  $x^4+2x^2-8m^2x+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m>0$?

Wolfram alpha says it is but gives no proof why. Eisenstein's criterion doesn't apply. I have no idea how to proceed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried reducing modulo a prime? There is a theorem along the following lines; if you reduce f modulo a prime and the degree doesn't change, then irreducibility modulo the prime implies irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$. Reducing modulo 3 shows that it is irreducible if $m\neq 1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly there are no integer (hence no rational roots), so we need to only check for quadratic factors. So we need to only check for the form
$$x^4+2x^2-8m^2x+1=(x^2+ax\pm1)(x^2-ax\pm1)$$
which gives $2-a^2=2$ and $\pm2a=-8m^2$ which is possible only when $a=m=0$.

Comment: That works. I was struggling for a while trying to show that it has no rational roots. But from the rational root theorem $x=\pm 1$ if x is a rational root of the above polynomial which leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Its irreducibility follows nicely from Perron's criterion when applied to reciprocal $g(x)=x^4f(1/x)=x^4-8m^2x^3+2x^2+1$:

> **Perron's criterion:** Let $P(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $|a_{n-1}| > 1 + |a_{n-2}| + \dots + |a_0|$, then $P(x)$ is irreducible.

Since $8m^2> 1+2+1 = 4$ clearly holds for $m>0$, it follows $g(x)$ is irreducible, and particularly $f(x)$ is irreducible as well.

Comment: One can find Perron's criterion at http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/intpoly.pdf